# LIKE-comparison with wildcard between value from table and value from atlas_feature for filtering attribute table using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, filter, comparison

I am trying to filter an attribute table in QGIS Print Composer based on the current active atlas feature:

I have a table with an "id" column with and some records that have these values in the "id" column:

```
048-
048-1
048-2
048-2i
048-2ii
```

My current atlas feature is 048-2 (i.e. @atlas_feature, 'ref' evaluates to "048-2")

I'd like the table to filter (show) only the records that contain "048-2" and may contain more characters after it, so it should filter to this:

```
048-2
048-2i
048-2ii
```

If I use the expression:

```
"id" LIKE attribute ( @atlas_feature, 'ref' )
```

I only get "048-2" which makes sense.

Filtering by

```
"id"  LIKE  '048-2%'
```

gets the results I need.

But how can I filter this table according to my need by using attribute ( @atlas_feature, 'ref' ? – or, where to put the "%" in the following expression?

```
"id" LIKE attribute ( @atlas_feature, 'ref' )
```

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer. One had to add the "%" sign with a concat operator:

```
"id"  LIKE  concat(attribute ( @atlas_feature, 'ref'),'%')
```

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to read by removing as many functions as possible. Not sure if the syntax works but something like this:  
  
`"id" LIKE attribute(@atlas_feature, 'ref') + '%'`

Comment: The "+" operator is for values and did not work in this case. I guess we have to explicitly use "concat".